# How can I find memory leak in android app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, firebase

I'm developing an android kind-of-gallery-app with Firebase, so I will have plenty of images. I know that I need to be careful about memory management.

When I was searching how to find memory leak in android apps, I came across with [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary). It looks really great, so I used in my app.

Basically my app has 3 fragments, which are Drawer, ProductGrid and ProductDetail. Sometimes LeakCanary says that I have a memory leak in ProductGrid, but I couldn't find it! Usually, adapters or static methods or listeners could cause memory leak because of Context object, but my knowledge is not sufficient to say 'aah that's because of here'

Here are the classes. Where is the leak?(If you suggest me anything that I can improve my code or approach, I would be appreciated!)

Because of body character limit, I put the [link](http://ademilhan.com/log.txt) leak canary log file.

**How I suspect there is a memory leak**

First of all, LeakCanary shows a dialog and logs the dump. Second thing is, when I click on an item in drawer, in grid and in detail like 15 times(respectively), memory usage increases. It starts with 18M, increases 22M-23M after showing 3 images(normal). Then it heads up to 29M-30M after clicking on 15 times. If you click on around 30-40, memory usage increases 34M-35M

**Edit**: I've just figured out that, if I open and close drawer, memory usage increases 0.05M everytime, so one time opening and closing drawer costs 0.1M! What am i missing?

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements DrawerListener {

  private Toolbar mToolbar;

  private Drawer drawerFragment;
  private HomePage homeFragment;

  private FragmentHelper fh = new FragmentHelper();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (homeFragment == null)
      homeFragment = new HomePage();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

      drawerFragment = (Drawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
      drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
      drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
      drawerFragment.setRetainInstance(true);

      displayView(null);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_home) {
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

      fh.replace(getSupportFragmentManager(), homeFragment, R.id.container_body);
      return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position, Category category) {
    displayView(category);
  }

  private void displayView(Category category) {
    if (category != null) {
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle(category.getName());

      ProductGrid gridFragment = new ProductGrid();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString(Product.CATEGORY_ID, category.getId());
      gridFragment.setArguments(args);

      fh.replace(getSupportFragmentManager(), gridFragment, R.id.container_body);
    } else {
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

      fh.replace(getSupportFragmentManager(), homeFragment, R.id.container_body);
    }
  }
}
```

**Drawer.java**

```
public class Drawer extends Fragment {

  private Firebase mFirebase;
  private Alert alert;

  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private View containerView;
  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
  private DrawerListener drawerListener;

  private DrawerAdapter mAdapter;

  private List<Category> mCategories;

  public Drawer() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    alert = new Alert(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer, container, false);

    mCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    mAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(mCategories);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInOutLeftItemAnimator(recyclerView));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mFirebase = new Firebase(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_ref))
          .child(FirebaseRoots.CATEGORY);

    Query query = mFirebase.orderByChild(Category.PRIO);

    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Category model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Category.class);
        model.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
        mCategories.add(model);

        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mCategories.size() - 1);
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mCategories.size() - 1);
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Category model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Category.class);
        model.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mCategories.size(); i++) {
          if (mCategories.get(i).getId().equals(model.getId())) {
            index = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        mCategories.set(index, model);

        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Category model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Category.class);
        model.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mCategories.size(); i++) {
          if (mCategories.get(i).getId().equals(model.getId())) {
            index = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        mCategories.remove(index);

        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        alert.show(firebaseError.toString());
      }
    });

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
          recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        Category category = mCategories.get(position);
        drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position, category);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
      }

      @Override
      public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

      }
    }));

    return layout;
  }

  public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
      @Override
      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
      }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
      }
    });
  }

  public void setDrawerListener(DrawerListener listener) {
    this.drawerListener = listener;
  }

}
```

**ProductGrid.java**

```
public class ProductGrid extends Fragment implements ChildEventListener{

  private Firebase mFirebaseRef;
  private Alert alert;

  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private GridAdapter mAdapter;

  private String categoryId;
  private ArrayList<Product> mProducts;

  private FileSystem fs;

  public ProductGrid() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.categoryId = getArguments().getString(Product.CATEGORY_ID);

    this.alert = new Alert(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    this.fs = new FileSystem(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, container, false);
    fieldInitialize(layout);

    mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new GridAdapter(mProducts, getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MarginDecoration(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_ref))
          .child(FirebaseRoots.PRODUCT);

    Query query = mFirebaseRef.orderByChild(Product.CATEGORY_ID).equalTo(categoryId);
    query.addChildEventListener(this);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        ProductDetail detailFragment = new ProductDetail();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("product", mProducts);
        args.putInt("position", position);
        detailFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_body, detailFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
      }

      @Override
      public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

      }
    }));

    return layout;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
  }

  public void fieldInitialize(View layout) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.product_grid_layout);
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Product model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
    model.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    mProducts.add(model);

    if (!fs.getFileNames().contains(model.getName() + FileExt.JPG.get())) {
      fs.writeImage(model.getName(), ImageUtil.base64ToBitmap(
            StringUtil.getBase64FromUrl(model.getImageData().getDataUrl())));
    }

    Collections.sort(mProducts);

    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mProducts.size() - 1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Product model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
    model.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

    fs.writeImage(model.getName(), ImageUtil.base64ToBitmap(
          StringUtil.getBase64FromUrl(model.getImageData().getDataUrl())));

    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mProducts.size(); i++) {
      if (mProducts.get(i).getId().equals(model.getId())) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    mProducts.set(index, model);

    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Product model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
    model.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

    fs.deleteImage(model.getName());

    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mProducts.size(); i++) {
      if (mProducts.get(i).getId().equals(model.getId())) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    mProducts.remove(index);

    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    alert.show(firebaseError.toString());
  }

  @Override public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = AcarsanApp.getRefWatcher(getActivity());
    refWatcher.watch(this);
  }
}
```

**ProductDetail.java**

```
public class ProductDetail extends Fragment {

  private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
  private ViewPager viewPager;

  private ArrayList<Product> products;
  private int position;

  public ProductDetail() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    products = (ArrayList<Product>) getArguments().getSerializable("product");
    position = getArguments().getInt("position");
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_detail, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.product_gallery);
    adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), products);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
  }
}
```

**FileSystem**

```
public class FileSystem {

  private Context mContext;

  public static final String PHOTOS_FOLDER = "photos";

  public FileSystem(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
  }

  public void writeImage(String name, Bitmap bitmap) {
    String filename = name + FileExt.JPG.get();

    File dir = mContext.getDir(PHOTOS_FOLDER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File fileWithinDir = new File(dir, filename);
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {

      outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinDir);
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  public List<String> getFileNames() {
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();

    File file = mContext.getDir(PHOTOS_FOLDER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (File f : files) {
      fileNames.add(f.getName());
    }
    return fileNames;
  }

}
```

**ImageUtil**

```
public class ImageUtil {

  public static Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String encodedImage) {
    if (encodedImage == null)
      return null;

    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is ImageUtil.base64ToBitmap and fs.writeImage ?

Comment: First of all, LeakCanary shows a dialog and logs the dump. Second thing is, when I click on an item in drawer, in grid and in detail like 15 times(respectively), memory usage increases. It starts with 18M, increases 22M-23M after showing 3 images(normal). Then it heads up to 29M-30M after clicking on 15 times. If you click on around 30-40, memory usage increases 34M-35M

Comment: do u recycle/free the bitmaps?

Comment: I'm using picasso, do I still need to free bitmap? I thought picasso handles it

Comment: There is no recycling of the Bitmap object in FileSystem.writeImage. So, this object once created in ImageUtils, remains in memory forever

Comment: @AterLux Instead of using ImageUtil, I created a bitmap inside child_added callback, and recycle bitmap after attaching an imageview. Same problem exists!

Comment: You shouldn't have to recycle bitmaps except when you use a very old version of Android. Have you tried TraceView?

Comment: Maybe help http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html